# Are there special sample size calculations involved for the analysis of residuals in a contingency table?

Tags: chi-squared-test, sample-size, residuals, statistical-power

This is a purely theoretical question (for the moment at least), so not a lot of details to share. If I plan an analysis of residuals following a chi-squared test of independence, I was wondering if I should calculate my sample size differently compared with when I plan "just" a chi-squared test without analysing the (adjusted standardized) residuals.

My usual workflow is the following for the "vanilla" chi-squared test of independence: I choose a minimum effect size (Cohen's w) of interest, plus my alpha and power levels (usually 0.05 and 0.8), and then I plug all that in the G*power software or in the R pwr library.

As far as I know, these software do not have special options for the case of analysis of residuals in contingency tables, so I guess that I would have to write a script myself if necessary to determine the required sample size.

But in fact, I have absolutely no idea if I'm off the tracks, or if residual analysis is really a problem that should be tackled differently (and if it's the case, where to begin).

I guess I would have to figure out a minimum effect size of interest for each cell, apply a multiple test correction to my alpha level, but besides that I've no idea what to do to determine the required sample size.

Thanks for any guidance.